# Is the following structure considered as a design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, javafx, structure

I have implemented the following simplyfied structure using JavaFX:

**App.java**

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    MyConnector myconnector = new MyConnector();
    LeftPane leftPane = new LeftPane(myconnector);
    RightPane rightPane = new RightPane(myconnector);
}
```

**MyConnector.java**

```
public class MyConnector {
    private Button button;                       // getters, setters
    private Field field;                         // getters, setters
}
```

**LeftPane.java**

```
public LeftPane extends FlowPane {
    private Button button;                       // getters, setters
    private MyConnector myConnector;             // in constructor, getters, setters

    public LeftPane(myConnector) {
        this.button = new Button();
        this.myConnector = myConnector;
        this.myConnector.setField(this.button);  // add to the MyConnector
    }

    an event on action {
        this.myConnector.getField().setEditable(false);
        this.button.setDisable(true);
    } 
}
```

**RightPane.java**

```
public RightPane extends FlowPane {
    private TextField field;                     // getters, setters
    private MyConnector myConnector;             // in constructor, getters, setters

    public LeftPane(myConnector) {
        this.field = new TextField();
        this.myConnector = myConnector;
        this.myConnector.setField(this.field);   // add to the MyConnector
    }

    an event on action {
        this.myConnector.getButton().setDisable(true);
        this.field.setEditable(false);
    } 
}
```

Shortly it means, that I have two panes containing the first one the `Button` and the second one the `TextField`. On some event triggers, I want to disable both of them at once. This solution works perfectly.

I wanted firstly avoid this cross-like code, that leads to the `NullPointerException` only:

```
LeftPane leftPane = new LeftPane(this.rightPane.getField());
RightPane rightPane = new RightPane(this.leftPane.getButton());
```

Is the structure above I have used the correct approach and is it one of the recognized design patterns? If so, what is its name? I've been thinking over `Adapter` or `Bridge` but I can't refactor my structure into one of them.

If my structure isn't a design pattern at all, does there exist one dealing with the same thing? or does there exist a better approach?

Comment: Just looks like object composition, not necessarily a pattern

Comment: It might be a pattern, though. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/structural_patterns

Comment: Trying to recognize patterns "in the wild" is difficult, if not impossible. A true pattern solves a recurring problem. The SO tag for [tag:design-patterns] says, "A design pattern (not to be confused with a regular expression pattern) is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem in software design." It's difficult because the problem may or may not be there? Many people apply patterns just for the sake of it, not because the problem they are supposed to solve is really there. Problems aren't always documented formally (in requirements, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not a design pattern. Design patterns are examples of good design (at least with respect to a specific problem). What you've done is definetly not good design:

- You hardcode the fields in the `MyConnector` class; `MyConnector` only works for `Button`/`TextField` combination; You cannot add more than 2 elements or different elements without rewriting the `MyConnector` class. Also this limits reuseability.
- This one is even worse: You've got a high coupling between `LeftPane` and `RightPane`. You deactivate the UI of one pane from the other pane **accessing the internals of the other pane**. Let's say you want to add rectangle to `LeftPane` that is filled with green/red color, if the pane is active/disabled. In this case you need to modify the code of `RightPane` to do this for you.

---

In this case it would be appropriate to use the observer pattern. This allows you to add an arbitrary number of elements and no element need to know about the internals of the other:

```
BooleanProperty connector = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
LeftPane leftPane = new LeftPane(connector);
RightPane rightPane = new RightPane(connector);
```

```
public LeftPane extends FlowPane {
    private Button button;
    private BooleanProperty myConnector;

    public LeftPane(myConnector) {
        this.button = new Button();
        this.myConnector = myConnector;
        ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            this.button.setDisable(newValue);
        };
        myConnector.addListener(listener);
        listener.changed(null, null, myConnector.get());
    }

    an event on action {
        this.myConnector.set(false);
    } 
}
```

```
public RightPane extends FlowPane {
    private TextField field;
    private BooleanProperty myConnector;

    public LeftPane(myConnector) {
        this.field = new TextField();
        this.myConnector = myConnector;
        ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            // update this UI part
            this.field.setEditable(newValue);
        };
        myConnector.addListener(listener);
        listener.changed(null, null, myConnector.get());
    }

    an event on action {
        this.myConnector.set(false);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well, there are some design patterns ('anti-patterns') that are deliberate instances of bad design ...